# CSS в верстке рассылок

Tags: рассылка

Кто верстает рассылки. Поделитесь. Во всех статьях призывают использовать таблицы чуть ли не для всего.
1. Можно ли задать основную внешнюю таблицу, а для внутреннего лэйаута использовать div-ы с width-ами, padding-ами и margin-ами? Или вообще обойтись без таблиц.
2. Как лучше верстать списки с нестандартными маркерами?
3. Какие программы/сервисы сейчас являются слабым звеном?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Про это лучше забыть. Только таблицы, если не хотите, чтобы содержимое расползалось в различных почтовых клиентах.
2. Маркер в виде картинки и - таблицы :)
3. У всех почтовых клиентов свои ограничения, лучше тестировать - так же, как в случае с браузерами.